# System.NullReferenceException error when trying to update the database using EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, connector-net

I am making an e-commerce app to try and learn .NET 7. I set up the models and database connection the first time and everything worked great. After I continued to develop the back-end, I added another migration and tried to update the database, but this error showed up:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> ```
> at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MySQLMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(RenameColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__82_22(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)  
> at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MySQLMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)    
> at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MySQLMigrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)    
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.<GetMigrationCommandLists>b__2()  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.<GetMigrationCommandLists>b__2()   
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> ```

I tried removing a migration and adding a new one. I tried deleting and creating the model snapshot and the same error persists. I don't really understand the error as well. Is it saying that there's a problem with my model entities or what?

When updating the database with the `--verbose` setting, this is what it shows right before the error above occurs

````
Applying migration '20230930105241_FinalMigration'.
'DataContext' disposed.
Disposing connection to database 'ecommerce' on server 'localhost'.
Disposed connection to database 'ecommerce' on server 'localhost' (2ms).```
````

Comment: This looks like a bug in the `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore`  NuGet package. I recommend you try a different version of the package and/or file an issue with the authors.

Comment: Which driver are you using? Oracle's is full of bugs which is why most developers use the truly open source [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) provider. And, needless to say, Oracle's provider doesn't work with MariaDB

Comment: It's quite possible Oracle's provider doesn't support migrations in EF Core. The [EF Core pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html) don't mention migrations at all. They're only mentioned in the EF 6 Classic docs